# How to dynamically iterate over the output of an upstream task to create parallel tasks in airflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

Consider the following example of a DAG where the first task, `get_id_creds`, extracts a list of credentials from a database. This operation tells me what users in my database I am able to run further data preprocessing on and it writes those ids to the file `/tmp/ids.txt`. I then scan those ids into my DAG and use them to generate a list of `upload_transaction` tasks that can be run in parallel.

My question is: Is there a more idiomatically correct, dynamic way to do this using airflow? What I have here feels clumsy and brittle. How can I directly pass a list of valid IDs from one process to that defines the subsequent downstream processes?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
import sys

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

import ds_dependencies

SCRIPT_PATH = os.getenv('DASH_PREPROC_PATH')
if SCRIPT_PATH:
    sys.path.insert(0, SCRIPT_PATH)
    import dash_workers
else:
    print('Define DASH_PREPROC_PATH value in environmental variables')
    sys.exit(1)

default_args = {
  'start_date': datetime.now(),
  'schedule_interval': None
}

DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='dash_preproc',
  default_args=default_args
)

get_id_creds = PythonOperator(
    task_id='get_id_creds',
    python_callable=dash_workers.get_id_creds, 
    provide_context=True,
    dag=DAG)

with open('/tmp/ids.txt', 'r') as infile:
    ids = infile.read().splitlines()

for uid in uids:
    upload_transactions = PythonOperator(
        task_id=uid,
        python_callable=dash_workers.upload_transactions,
        op_args=[uid],
        dag=DAG)
    upload_transactions.set_downstream(get_id_creds)
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517798/proper-way-to-create-dynamic-workflows-in-airflow

Comment: @JuanRiaza That was it, thanks a lot. The solution I ended up using simplifies the code substantially enough that I posted my solution as a separate answer -- I didn't have any need for `Xcom` at the end of the day

Answer (score 6):

Per @Juan Riza's suggestion I checked out this link: [Proper way to create dynamic workflows in Airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41517798/proper-way-to-create-dynamic-workflows-in-airflow). This was pretty much the answer, although I was able to simplify the solution enough that I thought I would offer my own modified version of the implementation here:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import sys

from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

import ds_dependencies

SCRIPT_PATH = os.getenv('DASH_PREPROC_PATH')
if SCRIPT_PATH:
    sys.path.insert(0, SCRIPT_PATH)
    import dash_workers
else:
    print('Define DASH_PREPROC_PATH value in environmental variables')
    sys.exit(1)

ENV = os.environ

default_args = {
  # 'start_date': datetime.now(),
  'start_date': datetime(2017, 7, 18)
}

DAG = DAG(
  dag_id='dash_preproc',
  default_args=default_args
)

clear_tables = PythonOperator(
  task_id='clear_tables',
  python_callable=dash_workers.clear_db,
  dag=DAG)

def id_worker(uid):
    return PythonOperator(
        task_id=uid,
        python_callable=dash_workers.main_preprocess,
        op_args=[uid],
        dag=DAG)

for uid in capone_dash_workers.get_id_creds():
    clear_tables >> id_worker(uid)
```

`clear_tables` cleans the database that will be re-built as a result of the process. `id_worker` is a function that dynamically generates new preprocessing tasks, based on the array of ID values returned from `get_if_creds`. The task ID is just the corresponding user ID, though it could easily have been an index, `i`, as in the example mentioned above.

**NOTE** That bitshift operator (`<<`) looks backwards to me, as the `clear_tables` task should come first, but it's what seems to be working in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that Apache Airflow is a workflow management tool, ie. it determines the dependencies between task that the user defines in comparison (as an example) with apache Nifi which is a dataflow management tool, ie. the dependencies here are data which are transferd through the tasks.

That said, i think that your approach is quit right (my comment is based on the code posted) **but** Airflow offers a concept called `XCom`. It allows tasks to "cross-communicate" between them by passing some data. How big should the passed data be ? it is up to you to test! But generally it should be not so big. I think it is in the form of key,value pairs and it get stored in the airflow meta-database,ie you can't pass files for example but a list with ids could work.

Like i said you should test it your self. I would be very happy to know your experience. [Here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/models.py) is an example dag which demonstrates the use of `XCom` and [here](http://pythonhosted.org/airflow/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms) is the necessary documentation. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @sdikby. I spent some time yesterday looking into `Xcom` and feel like I have a strong conceptual grasp of how it exchanges data between tasks. Where I don't see this applying in this case is that I am looking for a means of creating an arbitrary number of tasks _based_ on the output of an upstream task in the same DAG. It's occurred to me that I could create two DAGs, one to define the task parameters and other to execute, but that's not ideal because I lose the dependency relation. Do you agree that `Xcom` doesn't support this application, or am I missing somehing?

Comment: External links are bad and dead.