# Airflow tree view inversion bug?

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am running a couple active DAGs on Google Cloud composer (managed airflow) and it seems the tree view of all my DAGS are rendering inverted.

Note the following DAG:

```
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator

default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "start_date": datetime(2020, 4, 26),
    "depends_on_past": False,
    "email_on_failure": False,
    "email_on_retry": False,
    "email": "youremail@host.com",
    "retries": 1,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=5)
}

with DAG(dag_id="Dummy_test", schedule_interval="@daily", default_args=default_args, catchup=True) as dag:
    op1 = DummyOperator(task_id='op1', dag=dag)
    op2 = DummyOperator(task_id='op2', dag=dag)
    op3 = DummyOperator(task_id='op3', dag=dag)
    op4 = DummyOperator(task_id='op4', dag=dag)
    op5 = DummyOperator(task_id='op5', dag=dag)
    op6 = DummyOperator(task_id='op6', dag=dag)
    op7 = DummyOperator(task_id='op7', dag=dag)
    op8 = DummyOperator(task_id='op8', dag=dag)
    op9 = DummyOperator(task_id='op9', dag=dag)

    op1 >> op2
    op2 >> op3
    op3 >> op4
    op4 >> op5
    op5 >> op6
    op6 >> [op7, op8, op9]
```

It renders correctly in Graph view:

[image: It renders correctly in Graph view]

But the tree view is inverted?

[image]

Is this a UI bug, or am I defining my dependencies incorrectly? This is happening on all my dags, not just this simple dummy example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [understanding the tree view in apache airflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47856195/understanding-the-tree-view-in-apache-airflow)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to itroulli and his comments, I now see this is the expected behavior. Thanks!